# SPSS Syntax - How to deal with missing values through SPSS Syntax

Tags: syntax, spss, missing-data, montecarlo, markov-models

Im new in this forum.

I have to do a presentation on how SPSS deals with missing values.  Specificaly, our professor gave us the task to:

1) Find out if, besides the functions accesible through the menus, there are functions accesible via SPSS Syntax to deal with missing values (that is, functions that are only accesible via Syntax).

2) In multiple imputation: What is the exact procedure done by the Markov Monte Carlo method offered in the menus. Are there white papers, or academic papers explaining the exact procedure?

Kind regards for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Command Syntax Reference from the Help menu.  You will find that various procedure have options not included in the dialogs.  Start with DESCRIPTIVES and REGRESSION.
2. Open the Algorithms item from the Help menu and look at multiple imputation.